# QArrayData error, linking Qt libraries with CMake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, mingw, qt-creator

What I've been trying to do is to link Qt libraries to my project with CMake. I would use CMake GUI to generate MakeFile and then run MinGW32-make on it, which would give me '[File Name].exe' as intended. However, whenever I run the executable file, I get a message saying:

"The procedure entry point _ZN10QArrayData10deallocateEPS_jj could not be located in the dynamic link library etc."

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpdwK.jpg

I initially built this software using Qt Creator and QMake, so I can confirm that the program has been tested and does work, but as I have to include an API, it requires me to use CMake instead.

I have done a lot of research and experimenting mostly with the CMakeLists.txt, but unfortunately, I'm not that good at it and I kinda suspect that's where the problem lies.

Comment: I think this means you have alternate versions (probably older) of dlls required somewhere in your path and those are being used instead of the correct dlls. Check your PATH variable.

Comment: Make sure that the Qt dlls you have in your path were compiled for mingw. I expect having MSVC Qt binaries in your PATH is one way to cause this error.