# QArrayData error, linking Qt libraries with qmake

Tags: c++, qt, gnu-make, qmake

I am trying follow the instructions published here:

https://www.linux.org/threads/c-tutorial-create-qt-applications-without-qtcreator.18409/

but in a PC running Windows 10, to build a Qt application createdwith the Atom editor. I have this 3 files in my project right now:

**qt_main.cpp**

```
#include <QtWidgets>

#include "mainwidget.h"

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        MainWidget w;
        w.show();
        return a.exec();
    }
```

**mainwidget.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWIDGET_H
#define MAINWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class QPushButton;
class QTextBrowser;

class MainWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWidget();
private:
   QPushButton* button_;
   QTextBrowser* textBrowser_;
};

#endif // MAINWIDGET_H
```

**mainwidget.cpp**

```
#include <QtWidgets>

#include "mainwidget.h"

MainWidget::MainWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
   button_ = new QPushButton(tr("Push Me!"));
   textBrowser_ = new QTextBrowser();
   QGridLayout *mainLayout = new QGridLayout;
   mainLayout->addWidget(button_,0,0);
   mainLayout->addWidget(textBrowser_,1,0);
   setLayout(mainLayout);
   setWindowTitle(tr("Connecting buttons to processes.."));
}

MainWidget::~MainWidget()
{
   delete button_;
   delete textBrowser_;
}
```

I execute this commands, in sequence:

```
qmake -project
add `QT += widgets` to the qt_main.pro file generated
qmake qt_main.pro
make
```

After that, the EXE file is generated without error, but when I try run it, I got the error:

"The procedure entry point _ZN10QArrayData10deallocateEPS_jj could not be located in the dynamic link library etc."

I try follow the suggested on the comments for the question:

[QArrayData error, linking Qt libraries with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46654763/qarraydata-error-linking-qt-libraries-with-cmake)

and check my PATH. right now, the only directory containing qt DLLs is the one:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.14.0\5.14.0\mingw73_64\bin
```

(this directory was createwd by the Qt offline installer).

Anyone can give a hint of how to solve this issue?

Comment: Check what dlls are missing with Dependency Walker. Maybe MinGW dlls (libwinpthread-1.dll, libstdc++-6.dll, libgcc_s_seh-1.dll) or some other Qt dlls?

Comment: I check that, the Dependency Walker throws some errors telling so e DLLs are missing. All of them start with `API-MS-WIN-` or `EXT-MS-`. which DLLs are those? the result: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ajj5fjmHHQENmxfUpQ1KyZydUKp3?e=XBQ5s2

Comment: Qt5core.dll and qt5widgetd.dll (or their dependencies) are missing, make sure that you have them in PATH or in directory with your exe file. To be sure, you must expand them on the list.

Comment: As far as I can tell, based on the screen, you have MinGW libraries available for the executable.

Comment: I add Qt5Core, Qt5Gui and Qt5Widget DLLs to the same directory where my executable was, and now I am getting the error: "the initalization failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized".